# How can I change marker position and change google Map view with it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set my android App Google Map View to bottom of the screen but it does not changes its position to bottom. I am trying to replicate a GoogleMap/Waze kind of navigation feature in my Android Application.

**Marker Code**: Here I set the marker position to custom position according to user position and set a custom icon.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(userlatLng);
markerOptions.icon(markerIcon);
markerOptions.rotation(userlocation.getBearing());
markerOptions.title("Current Position");
markerOptions.anchor((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5);
markerOptions.flat(true);
currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

**Camera Position** I am changing the Camera position accourding to User current location with the zoom level of 20.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(userlatLng)
                .zoom(20)
                .bearing(userlocation.getBearing())
                .tilt(45)
                .build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

I wanted to ask how can I drop the icon to the bottom of the screen and show the remaining route on wide angle screen.

[image: Mobile App Current view that is showing the Icon in the middle]

[image: Mobile App Icon Position that I want to set]

Answer (score 1):

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(userlatLng);
markerOptions.icon(markerIcon);
markerOptions.anchor(whereIwantIt,whereIwantIt); // You need to add an anchor tag
markerOptions.rotation(userlocation.getBearing());
markerOptions.title("Current Position");
markerOptions.anchor((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5);
markerOptions.flat(true);
currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

You need to add anchor tag.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

Answer (score 0):

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(userlatLng);
markerOptions.icon(markerIcon);
markerOptions.rotation(userlocation.getBearing());
markerOptions.title("Current Position");
markerOptions.anchor((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5);
markerOptions.flat(true);
currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
currentLocationMarker.setPosition(userlatLng);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap google map in a ScrollView but disable scrollable.
[image]